# Cannot pass idpHint option to Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am using IDP provider for authentication and trying to bypass the standard keycloak login screen (so I need to go immediately to the IDP specific authorization screen). According to this documentation https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/identity-broker/suggested.html we can simply provide idpHint for this. Though that doesn't work.

`let keycloakAuth : any = new Keycloak('keycloak.json');
keycloakAuth.createLoginUrl({idpHint: 'ad-oidc'});`

It failed with

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirectUri' of undefined
    at Keycloak.kc.createLoginUrl (keycloak-core.js:212)`

As far as I understand that's because adapter is not created yet. So probably we need to pass this option sometimes later (but not sure at which phase).

I was able to do this only by hardcoding the idpHint inside of the keycloak-core.js itself temporarily. Looking forward to avoid this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem like this:

```
let kc = Keycloak('/backend/frontend.json');
let kcLogin = kc.login;
kc.login = (options) => {
  options.idpHint = 'some-hint';
  kcLogin(options);
};
kc.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success((authenticated) => {
  console.log('Logged in!');
}});
```

This way the very first login attempt already uses the hint. I somehow don't get, why there is no simple way to use the idpHint option, the inceptor is the only way I found to use it, without directly patching the keycloak.js file.

It would be perfect, if the Keycloak constructor just would accept an idpHint option.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize the keycloak object first.

You don't need to call createLoginUrl(), you need to call login(options) which by its turn going to call createLoginUrl.

```
var keycloak = new keycloak(JSON);
keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated){
 if(authenticated){
   console.log("logged in");
}
else{
   keycloak.login({idpHint:'ad-oidc'});
}
}).error(function(){
console.log("failed to initialize");
});
```

Sorry there might be syntax error but I hope it explains how to do it.